# Why WebMvcTest tries to load all configurations?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I wrote a simple controller class and trying to test with `@WebMvcTest`

```java
@RequiredArgsController
class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;
}
```

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;
}
```

The the test seems trying to load all configurations such as datasources an so on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't. Why do you say that it "seems trying to load all configurations such as datasources an so on."?

Comment: @JoãoDias I see a lot of logs print unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing what I experienced for others.

It seems the (sole) `Application` has some responsibilities.

```java
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = {
                Application.class,
                ...
        }
)
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                ...
        }
)
class Application {
}
```

When my `@WebMvcTest` loads it seems it search an `@SpringBootConfiguration` or whatever and it leads to load all configurations.

I put following class next to my `@WebMvcTest` classes.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
class ...TestConfiguration {

}
```

And put following annotations on my `@WebMvcTest` classes.

```java
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {
                ...TestConfiguration.class,
                SomeService.class,
                AnotherComponent.class
        }
)
@WebMvcTest(
        controllers = {
                MyController.class
        }
)
class MyControllerTest {

    @SpyBean
    private SomeService someService;

    @MockBean
    private AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

Comment: Adding `...TestConfiguration.class` (which has `@SpringBootApplication`) might be the problem.